# Nothing happen when submitting Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

It might be obvious, but I need another pair of eyes to get it. Clicking my "Submit" button doesn't produce anything (not a redirect, just nothing).

The Rails 4 app is a booking system for car parks near airports. Here is everything:

**routes.rb**:

```
Parkix::Application.routes.draw do

...
resources :books
....

root to: "books#index"

end
```

**books_controller.rb**:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

def index
    @book = Book.new
end

def create
    @book = Book.new params[:book]
    render "index"
end

end
```

**book.rb** (the model):

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

attr_accessor :airport, :start_date, :start_time, :end_date, :end_time

belongs_to :park
belongs_to :user
has_many :prices, through: :parks

before_validation :generate_dates

private

def generate_dates
    self.start = Time.strptime "#{self.start_date} #{self.start_time}", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
    self.end = Time.strptime "#{self.end_date} #{self.end_time}", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
end

end
```

**books/index.html.erb**:

```
<%= form_for Book.new, url: { action: "create" }, method: :post do |f| %>

<%= f.text_field :airport, placeholder: "Airport" %>
<%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "Start date" %>
<%= f.text_field :start_time, value: "10:00", placeholder: "Start time" %>
<%= f.text_field :end_date, placeholder: "End date" %>
<%= f.text_field :end_time, value: "10:00", placeholder: "End time" %>
<%= f.text_field :count_people, placeholder: "Count people" %>
<%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

As I said before, nothing happen when I click on the submit button. Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your submit event is maybe catched by a javascript. Have you tried with javascript disabled? Otherwise, I would take a look to an HTML5 validation error…

Comment: You are right Julien, this was due to JS catching the form submit event. Question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your help, but this was due to JS catching form-submit event. Not a Ruby problem.

I'll close this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok step one, you do not need to write the url, rails can infer it. so

```
<%= form_for Book.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :airport, placeholder: "Airport" %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_date, placeholder: "Start date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_time, value: "10:00", placeholder: "Start time" %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_date, placeholder: "End date" %>
  <%= f.text_field :end_time, value: "10:00", placeholder: "End time" %>
  <%= f.text_field :count_people, placeholder: "Count people" %>
  <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

step 2, Most important, you did not save it

```
def create
   @book = Book.new params[:book]
   @book.save!
   render "index"
end
```

or

```
def create
   @book = Book.create! params[:book]
   render "index"
end
```